# Converting data from .gdb into shapefile without ArcMap

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-online, convert, file-geodatabase, software-recommendations

I have a .gdb folder with LOCK Files, FREELIST Files, ATX Files, GDBINDEXES Files, GDBTABLE Files, GDBTABLEX Files and, SPX Files.

I want to convert the parcel data within this folder into a shapefile so that I can load it into ArcGIS online. If I still had my ArcGIS desktop version this would be a simple task however, I no longer have access to this version of the software.

Any ideas on how to get this parcel data into a shapefile?

I haven't tried downloading QGIS yet so I'm not sure if this software would have that capability as ArcMap 10.1 did.

Answer (score 20):

One option that may be a bit faster (less clicks) or you could call from a script would be to use ogr2ogr command (using OSGeo4wShell (which comes with installation of QGIS)).

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" C:/Temp/Shps C:/Temp/test.gdb
```

[image]

If you want to export out a subset you may use the same command above but at the end list out the table name(s) (e.g. parcel and citybnd).

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" C:/Temp/Shps C:/Temp/test.gdb parcel citybnd
```

Answer (score 15):

File Geodatabase in QGIS 2.4
[image]

Note: Use **Directory** rather than File

Once the file geodatbase is loaded save the shapefile

[image]

Comment: At least in 3.2+ I was able to just start QGIS then drag the folder into the program window and it imported everything into a new project