# Extract features in .gdb file based on their attributes

Tags: qgis, gdal, r, field-calculator, file-geodatabase

I have a .gdb file with >17,000 features. Simplified example of attributes table:

```
ID      NAME    DATE    ETC
0001    london  2012    12
0002    london  2012    23
0003    thame   2012    45
0004    thame   2012    56
0005    kent    2012    67
0006    london  2011    78
...
```

I have an Excel file with a list of ~250 names:

```
NAME
kent
essex
sussex
london
...
```

I want to **extract only the features with attributes that match the names in the Excel file and save them as shapefiles.** Multiple features share the same attributes. How to do this using FOSS? I think there is a function in ArcGIS called [FeatureClassToShapefile](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00120000003m000000) that does this.

I [found this code](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108006/how-to-convert-data-from-a-gdb-into-a-shapefile-without-arcmap) to run GDAL directly from the terminal to convert the .gdb to a shapefile:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" /test/extraction /test/test.gdb
```

I can select a subset of layers by appending these to the above code:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" /test/extraction /test/test.gdb example_layer
```

If I try to use the same formatting to select a subset of features I get the error:

> FAILURE: Couldn't fetch requested layer 'example_feature'!

Is this possible using this method? I've looked at the GDAL documentation [here](https://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) but couldn't find an answer.

I'm open to other solutions, using GDAL, R pr QGIS preferably.

Comment: There are several join methods you may do with ogr, see: > OGR SQL supports a limited form of one to one JOIN. This allows
> records from a secondary table to be looked up based on a shared key
> between it and the primary table being queried. https://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95746/join-a-csv-file-to-shapefile-using-gdal-ogr

Comment: Any chance you could give an example?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/156213)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was quite simple - I was able to open the .gdb file in QGIS and use the 'Select by Expression' function to select the fields I wanted. The formula I used was based on [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93572/using-qgis-to-select-by-expression#93594) post:

```
SCINAME IN (
'kent', 
'essex', 
'sussex', 
'london'
)
```

I was then able to save the selection as a shapefile.